# Id not specified in an update call

Tags: salesforce, integration, salesforce-lightning, boomi

I'm updating an integration where I'm trying to update the contact table in Salesforce using Boomi.  Below are my settings:

[image]

My XML profile looks like:

```
<Contact>
<AccountId>CONTACTSALESFORCEID</AccountId>
<LastName>LASTNAME</LastName>
<FirstName>FIRSTNAME</FirstName>
<Email>EMAILADDRESS</Email>
</Contact>
```

When I run the integration I get this error:

```
<statusCode>MISSING_ARGUMENT</statusCode>
<message>OBJ: Contact - Id not specified in an update call</message>
```

From what I see in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386242&type=1, this error appears when the file does not include a Salesforce record ID or the ID column was not properly mapped to the ID field.  This doesn't seem to be my issue.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the map that is being uploaded.  Only items that have a connecting line are being sent over.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<AccountId>CONTACTSALESFORCEID</AccountId>` smells like you mapped to a wrong field.

All Contact Ids across all salesforce instances start with `003`. Account Ids start with `001`. Check your data and then I'd say either

`<Id>CONTACTSALESFORCEID</Id>`

or

```xml
<Contact>
    <Id>CONTACTSALESFORCEID</Id>
    <AccountId>Some other field that has 001...</AccountId>
    <LastName>LASTNAME</LastName>
    <FirstName>FIRSTNAME</FirstName>
    <Email>EMAILADDRESS</Email>
</Contact>
```

Comment: The Account ID is being used to connect the Customer and Contact tables.  So although it's coming in, Boomi doesn't show it as part of the update that it's trying to make.  So the Account ID is part of the "request" profile, but not the "response" profile.  I have edited my question and added the mapping of what what is attempting to load to Salesforce.  My Contact ID is 0034u... and my Account ID is 0014u0...

Comment: Did my clarification help?

Comment: I don't have Boomi handy to try myself, sorry. Somehow your thing ends up with blank Contact.Id field. Is there a way to capture final request sent? If you'd do it as bulk api job you should be able to see request and response in target SF org's setup -> bulk...